# How can I increase ScreenCaptureView efficiency on iPad?

Tags: ios, video, uiview, screen, capture

I've been tasked with a new iOS project.  As part of this, I am essentially looking to take a series screenshots of a UIView with it's subviews, and compile them in to a video file.

I have searched about, and most topics on this reference [ScreenCaptureView](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673), which I have tried out and it works!

I am using iOS SDK 5.1, and have this compiled with the -fno-objc-arc applied to ScreenCaptureView.m in the build phases section.

Before reading further, please note that I do not always have access to hardware to test on, and have currently only tested in the Simulator.  When I get access to equipment to test on I shall update.

This is great on the iPhone, I find that because of the screen size this works smoothly and doesn't seem to lag at all.  I do get the occasional dropped frame, but that isn't my concern with this question.

I'm creating an app to record the screen on either the iPhone or the iPad.

When I am using the iPad simulator, the efficiency of ScreenCaptureView drops significantly.  I find that, presumably due to the resolution of the iPad display, it's having to work a lot harder to capture the screen and write it to a frame.

The video becomes jerky and misses a lot of frames.

How can I increase the efficiency of the ScreenCaptureView method, or is there another method I can use to capture what is displayed in a UIView?

I admit I am very new to image manipuation/video work in general, and have no experience outside to draw on.

Many thanks!

Comment: I've come up with a solution that is better: ScreenCaptureView handles the writing of the frames to video output at the same time, and seemingly on the main thread. I have stripped the code out so that the draw rect updates the currentScreen UIImage at the desired frame rate, and then created a subclass to write the video out on a background thread.  This has allowed me to have almost smooth video at iPad resolution.  I've tried this on an iPad2 and it's definitely acceptable for my needs, not tried it on a retina iPad yet.... dreading that! haha

Comment: any chance you'd be willing to share your subclass?

Comment: @Pete C  i am stuck at same problem. i have to record current view(also include subview) and make it video. \n Can you please help me ?

Comment: @AshokD - Apologies, I hav enot worked with the project, or tech in a very long time, and I have no access to the project any more either.